# Завершить процессы из папки AppData

Tags: c#

У меня имеется список расширение которые нужно завершить ( и удалить файл )

`string[] file = new string[] {"*.txt","*.exe"};` - Нужно сделать это в определённой директории: 
`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`

Есть метод завершения процесса

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool TerminateProcess(IntPtr hProcess, int uExitCode);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var target = Process.GetProcesses()First(p => 
    p.ProcessName.IndexOf("VMWare",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);

    TerminateProcess(target.Handle, 0);
}
```

Как завершить процессы из нужной мне директории ( через массив )?

Comment: Перечислять все процессы, для каждого получать полный путь. Дальше очевидно.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов,Как совместить получения списка процессов и добавить массив из папки appdata ? Не соображаю

Comment: Не надо ничего совмещать. Научитесь для начала получать полные пути всех процессов

Comment: К чему такие сложности? Зачем нужен WinApi если из коробки доступен свой убиватель процессов?

Answer (score 1):

Немного не понял, зачем тебе подтягивать функцию убиения процесса из WinApi, когда у процесса есть метод Kill.

По идее, функция будет выглядеть, как-то так:

```
 static void KillProcessByPartOfPath(string partOfPath)
        {
            var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (var process in processes)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Может произойти исключение если процесс системный
                    var fileName = process.MainModule.FileName;
                    if (fileName.IndexOf(partOfPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            process.Kill();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: А функция `process.kill()` имеет такие же права ( привилегии ) как и `TerminateProcess`?- Это же функция используются в Windows. Или же они чем-то отличаются. Я понимаю конечно что можно напрямую вызвать из коробки `foreach()`, подумал что будет правильнее использовать эту функцию, её часто используют в с++.

Comment: Все методы взаимодействия с Виндой- это обертки над WinApi. В этом можно убедится посмотрев исходники http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System,namespaces => должна иметь теже права. В С++ это используют так как С++ из коробки ничего не имеет.

Comment: Хм... У меня нормально хром 64 разрядный убился из 32 разрядного приложения.